# Compare two files and replace value in one of the file

Tags: bash, awk, replace, compare

I have to files. **AU.swo** and **Compare** files.
**AU.swo** contain data:

```
7844204020353125700125759G19
7855207010004191300200759119
7898211030001191500193359119
7898211030001212800212959G19
7898211030002212600212759G19
```

**Compare** contain data:

```
7844204G1
785520712
7898211G1
789821112
```

First seven values from of files is ID number, position 8 in Compare file is same as position 26 in AU.swo. What I want to do is replace number **9** from last position in AU.swo file. It should be looks like:

```
7844204020353125700125759G11
7855207010004191300200759112
7898211030001191500193359112
7898211030001212800212959G11
7898211030002212600212759G11
```

what is better to use? awk or sed command? Could you give me some hint how can I do this? 
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this `awk`:

```
awk 'NR == FNR {
   k[substr($0, 1, 7),substr($0, 8, 1)] = substr($0, 9, 1)
   next
}
(substr($0, 1, 7), substr($0, 26, 1)) in k {
   sub(/9$/, k[substr($0, 1, 7),substr($0, 26, 1)])
} 1' compare AU.swo
```

```
7844204020353125700125759G11
7855207010004191300200759112
7898211030001191500193359112
7898211030001212800212959G11
7898211030002212600212759G11
```

Comment: It is properly tested and working code on 2 different versions of awk. Check for DOS line endings in your input files.

Comment: yes, you had a right. it was DOS line endings. I used dos2unix command for AU.swo file and now it's working properly. Thank you for your help

Comment: And what if I want to replace value 9 from another position, not from the end. For example in position 25 is value 9. I was trying to use  
`sub(substr($0,25,1)==9, k[substr($0, 1, 7),substr($0, 26, 1)])` but it's not working correctly

Comment: @Matej: Use `awk 'NR == FNR{k[substr($0, 1, 7),substr($0, 8, 1)] = substr($0, 9, 1); next} (substr($0, 1, 7), substr($0, 26, 1)) in k {$0 = substr($0,1,24) k[substr($0, 1, 7),substr($0, 26, 1)] substr($0,26)} 1' compare AU.swo`

Comment: it's returned values from compare file.

Comment: ok, maybe I am doing something wrong. Let me check this again.

Answer (score 0):

(Edit: another, nicer solution in python:)

`python -c 'for l in zip(open("AU.swo"), open("Compare")): print(l[0][:-2] + l[1][-2:-1])'`

This one also doesn't append on the exact length of the input strings.

My original solution, although quite ugly:

`paste -d '' <(sed 's/\(.*\).$/\1/' AU.swo) <(cut -c 9- Compare)`

How this works:

`sed 's/\(.*\).$/\1/' AU.swo` prints every line from `AU.swo` without the last character. We surround this with `<( ... )` to use this as the first input for `paste`.

`cut -c 9- Compare` prints the last character only of every line in `Compare`. Note that this assumes that each line is exactly 9 characters long.

`paste -d ''` takes each line of both inputs and prints them together on a single line.

Note that I tested this on linux and on mac OS this might not work.